# navsat_transform missing child_frame_id?

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-localization, navsat-transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am integrating GPS with odometry and IMU data.  I am using two instances of robot_localization, one for the continuous data.  That one feeds into a second one that gets gps data input.  I use navsat_transform to transform the gps data to the proper frame.  However, I found that the odometry output from navsat_transform.cpp is missing the child_frame_id.  The string for that value is correctly passed to baseLinkFrameId_ but is not used in the prepareGpsOdometry method.

The result is that robot_localization does not update when passed the odometry output from navsat_transform.  I was confused when I could not get output from robot_localization using the odometry from navsat_transform, yet could get output using other odometry sources as test inputs.  When I saw that the child frame was missing from the navsat_transform odometry, I modified the source to supply that value and then robot_localization started responding.  I don't know if that was the correct thing to do.  In fact, I suppose it was not, since nobody else is having this problem, it must mean I am doing something incorrectly, but I cannot figure out what that could be.

Changing this section in navsat_transform.cpp:

```
  gpsOdom.header.frame_id = worldFrameId_;
  gpsOdom.header.stamp = gpsUpdateTime_;
```

to the following:

```
  gpsOdom.header.frame_id = worldFrameId_;
  gpsOdom.child_frame_id = baseLinkFrameId_;
  gpsOdom.header.stamp = gpsUpdateTime_;
```

fixes the problem.  However, since the code is working for everyone else, I assume I am doing something wrong.
Here is the navsat_transform.launch file:

```
<node pkg="robot_localization" type="navsat_transform_node" name="navsat_transform_node" output= "screen" respawn="true">

  <param name="magnetic_declination_radians" value="0"/>

  <param name="yaw_offset" value="0"/>
  <param name="use_odometry_yaw" value="true" />   <!-- when true, we use yaw from the UKF, when false we use imu_data -->   
  <param name="wait_for_datum" value="false" />     <!-- when true, we use the datum parameter for initial location, when false we get it from the UKF -->

  <remap from="/imu/data" to="/imu_center" />
  <remap from="/gps/fix" to="/fix" />
  <remap from="/odometry/filtered" to="/odom_ukf" />
  <remap from="/odometry/gps" to="/odom_navsat" /> 

</node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215775/navsat_transform-missing-child_frame_id?/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2015-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was not properly including the first robot_localization output into the gps robot_localization odom input.  Since it was not receiving that data, it was not updating.

---

Originally posted by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) with karma: 875 on 2015-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [nav_msgs/Odometry](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Odometry.html) message contains two primary parts, a [geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovariance.html), and a [geometry_msgs/TwistWithCovariance](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TwistWithCovariance.html) (velocity). Each is reported in a different frame. The pose data gets reported in a world-fixed frame (typically *map* or *odom*), and the velocity data is reported in the robot's body frame (typically base_link). See [REP 105](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html). The nav_msgs/Odometry message needs some way to report the frame_ids for the pose data and velocity data, so the header's frame_id is reserved for the pose data, and the child_frame_id field refers to the velocity.

`navsat_transform_node` converts navsat data into local world-frame position data. As such, the node does not report velocity. In the long term, the output should really be changed to a geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceStamped message, but regardless, the velocity data in the Odometry message is not filled out, and so we don't bother setting the `child_frame_id`.

As to why this appears to make a difference for you, I couldn't say without more information, e.g., sample messages for your inputs and your entire `ukf_localization_node` launch files. Bag files are also extremely helpful.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2015-08-13**:
Here is a link to a folder with bag files for both cases (with and without the child frame, so with and without a response from the gps robot_localization.  tf trees, messages, launch files are here too.
[data_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wf36cq8rl8750ty/AACNP6NVko1XSNcDzTbqVcOna?dl=0)

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2015-08-14**:
And, by the way, thanks so much both for your help with this and for the robot_localization package.  It is extremely useful, professionally written, and very well documented.

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2015-08-14**:
I think I figured it out-- I was not properly including the odom from the first robot_localization into the gps robot_localization.